# functional testing during development

Tags: python, testing

I am not exposed to many of the testing framework, and wonder any recommendation on achieving the following (functional testing) during development phase. Intention is to test a web application functionality (language agnostic?) though the exposed http (REST/JSON RPC) interface.

My backend in NOT written in Python, but because of the easiness of using `requests` library, and creating Ad hoc http request, I simply construct http POST/GET request with appropriate cookie, payload etc and check the response to validate the server correctness.

It is little tedious to enable specific test cases (comment out / boolean flag ), and verify the results. Any framework to make this more pleasant during the development phase where frequent changes are the norm.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your on the right track with `requests` you could tie that directly into [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) or any of the common python testing frameworks that exist, bit of background `requests` was actually written for testing `flask`

Answer (score 1):

Use `nose` to run your tests. In this case, you can declare base classes of your tests to be like this:

```
class SlowTestBase(BaseTestCase):
    slow = True
```

And run it like `nosetests --attr="slow"`, or to exclude them `--attr="!slow"`. You can find more on nose documentation at https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/